# SQL Update - Using Multiple Table Joins

Tags: sql

Wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction please.

I Have 3 tables...

**Table A** -
Code, Cost1, Cost2, Cost3

**Table B** - 
Code, ID

**Table C** -
ID, Price

Basically I need to update the Price Field on Table C with (Cost1+Cost2+Cost3) 
from Table A.
There is no direct link between the 2 tables, but A is linked to B via Code and B is linked to C via ID.

I can write a query to display Price and the Total Cost but can't get my head around how to do the Update.

Any pointers would be extremely welcome

Thanks 
Andrew

Comment: update c set select sum group by etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE TC
SET Price=(TA.Cost1+TA.Cost2+TA.Cost3) 
FROM TableA TA
INNER JOIN TableB TB ON TA.Code=TB.Code
INNER JOIN TableC TC ON TC.ID=TB.ID
```

I prefer writing my more complicated joins out first and then simply updating the alias. As you can see in the example, you could comment out the top two lines and simply put in a SELECT TC.ID,TA.Cost1+TA.Cost2+TA.Cost3 and see exactly what would change.